# Take screenshot via PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a chat system and I want to protect my users from malicious websites, and sometimes people sends a URL through the chat system, and users click on it and access some scam sites. I have that protect page like `redirect.php?url=someurl.com` that alerts the users that URL can be a malicious website, and the users have to click on `Continue` button to access the link. But I want to give them one more option which is `See a preview`, and clicking on it, a new tab will be opened with a screenshot, or if it's not possible only with `PHP` and `Javascript`, show a clean version of the page without `Javascript`.

How can I do this?

I'm planning of make use of `file_get_contents()`, save it to some preview text, cleaning the `<script>` tag of the page, but it'll be enough?

Comment: What about an `<iframe>`? That's probably more straight forward and less code requirements.

Comment: Yea, the clean version of the site without scripts will be shown in a little iframe. But the users won't be protected if I open it through an iframe without removing the scripts anyways.

Comment: Although I guess if you don't want them to go to it, then an iframe may not be the way to go. The `file_get_contents()` stripped of problematic tags should be good I would imagine.

Comment: This sounds like something similar to what browser previews show, for example browsershots.org. As far as I can remember, they actually need to run servers which load up the page, take a screenshot on that computer and upload it

Comment: Yea, I'll try it and see what happens. I'm afraid only about if the site contains some malicious code without using javascript, like a PHP redirect to another site or something like that.

Comment: just use an iframe. with the sandbox attribute, which lets you block JS among other stuff. particularly effective on "framebusting" scripts.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will not work if it is a single page application or an app that uses JS to build up the DOM. You would need a headless browser on the server to open the url and produce the screenshot for the user, but this will open a security hole in your server and is not advisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of such screen capture web service here:
[What's the best website screenshot capture API?](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-website-screenshot-capture-API)

But instead of doing that by yourself, I think you should go with those many public link-shortening service, like [t.co](https://support.twitter.com/articles/109623-about-twitter-s-link-service-http-t-co), because anti-malicious is already one of their purpose:

> Having a link shortener protects users from malicious sites that
>   engage in spreading malware, phishing attacks, and other harmful
>   activity. A link converted by Twitter’s link service is checked
>   against a list of potentially dangerous sites. Users are warned with
>   the error message below when clicking on potentially harmful URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :):  **html2canvas**

[outofdate] http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

--

Update: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com

Comment: Updated answer.